# Back-and-Forth Linspace Generator

Tags: python, numpy, geometry

I'm looking to have a generator function that returns points along a line, given a minimum-distance `k`. This is simple enough, and can be done with numpy as follows:

```
points = np.linspace(start, end, k)
```

However, I would like to generate the points as a sort of "increasing resolution", so that on a line from 0 to 1, the generator would yield:

```
1/2, 1/4, 3/4, 1/8, 3/8, 5/8, ...
```

Again, this is easy enough to do recursively (just accept the endpoints and call self on each half), but I'd like a generator that can achieve the same thing without having to fill an array with everything from the start, and without duplicate points.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Does 5/8th has to follow on 3/8? There is a known algorithm to generate a sequence with 1/2, 1/4, 3/4, 1/8, 5/8, 3/8, 7/8, 1/16, etc. This is considered as a good way for pseudo-Monte Carlo integration.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, yes I believe this is something called the "Lost Cow Algorithm"? Generating the points 3/8, 4/8, 5/8 would be simpler, but would have redundant points. This could be easily solved by checking against a set, but if there is a way to not generate redundant points in the first place - assuming that this is faster than using a set - that would be best.

Comment: no, the above set does not contain duplicates. It is only when the denominator changes that the *order* of the values is not incrementing. But it generates the same points without duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A way to achieve this is by using:

```
def infinite_linspace():
    den = 2
    while True:
        for i in range(1,den,2):
            yield i/den
        den <<= 1
```

Here we thus iterate with the *numerator* from 1 to `den-1` (inclusive), and then double the *denominator*.

The first 15 numbers are then:

```
>>> list(islice(infinite_linspace(), 15))
[0.5, 0.25, 0.75, 0.125, 0.375, 0.625, 0.875, 0.0625, 0.1875, 0.3125, 0.4375, 0.5625, 0.6875, 0.8125, 0.9375]
>>> [1/2,1/4,3/4,1/8,3/8,5/8,7/8,1/16,3/16,5/16,7/16,9/16,11/16,13/16,15/16]
[0.5, 0.25, 0.75, 0.125, 0.375, 0.625, 0.875, 0.0625, 0.1875, 0.3125, 0.4375, 0.5625, 0.6875, 0.8125, 0.9375]
```

We can even put more intelligence into it to obtain the *i*-th element relatively fast as well:

```
class Linspace:

    def __iter__(self):
        den = 2
        while True:
            for i in range(1,den,2):
                yield i/den
            den <<= 1

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if not isinstance(idx, int):
            raise TypeError('idx should be an integer')
        if idx < 0:
            raise ValueError('idx should be positive')
        den = denn = idx+1
        denn |= den >> 1
        while den != denn:
            den = denn
            denn |= denn >> 1
        denn += 1
        return (2*idx+3-denn)/denn
```

So now we can access in logarithmic time for instance the 10-th, 15-th and 123'456-th element:

```
>>> l = Linspace()
>>> l[9]
0.3125
>>> l[14]
0.9375
>>> l[123455]
0.8837966918945312
```

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for. Now I see that I forgot to double the denominator within the loop. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a shorter, pseudo O(1) way of directly computing the i-th element:

```
def jumpy(i):
    i = (i<<1) + 3
    return i / (1<<i.bit_length()-1) - 1

list(map(jumpy, range(15)))
# [0.5, 0.25, 0.75, 0.125, 0.375, 0.625, 0.875, 0.0625, 0.1875, 0.3125, 0.4375, 0.5625, 0.6875, 0.8125, 0.9375]
```